# Allow flagging from close review queue?

Tags: discussion, review, flags

While running through the close-votes queue on meta I saw a few questions that were now-resolved support requests.  These had been nominated for closure as off-topic, but that's not right -- the questions *were* on-topic, but no longer need attention.  The correct thing to do in that case, as I understand it, would be to tag them status-completed, which only moderators can do.

So I wanted to flag those questions to suggest that tag -- but flagging isn't available via the queue.

Is that intentional?  I can imagine that there might be other cases where we might want to flag while reviewing.

Comment: I've always just opened the question in a new tab and flagged from there.

Comment: Sure, I can do that, but it's a hassle (especially if there are several and I already have a bunch of tabs open) and it seems like a reasonable thing to want to do inline.  I mean, I can leave a comment inline and that seems bigger than flagging.

Comment: It looks like the system will now identify potential spam in the review queue (see [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/221680/review-queue-identified-post-as-spam-incorrectly-but-post-still-needs-to-be-clo)), but there is no way to explicitly deal with it from the queue.