# Review queue identified post as spam incorrectly, but post still needs to be closed

Tags: support, review, spam

I am going through the Close Vote queue on Drupal Answers, and just ran into a situation that I haven't encountered before.

In the [review for this post](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/review/close/27236), is the text

> Our system has identified this post as possible spam; please review carefully

I suspect this is because the post is from a 1-rep user and contains the text "live chat".

The post itself isn't spam, but it needs to be closed (it's a shopping list question).

So, what is the proper procedure here to close this out, but not get is marked as spam?

Comment: I'd imagine that you'd be fine just closing it as normal, since marking it as close-worthy isn't the same as marking it spam.

Comment: @DennisMeng That is what I think but I want to be sure.  In my case, I am a mod, so my action is binding and immediate.  I don't want to get this poor soul marked as a spammer.

Comment: I strongly suspect the system is using a little bit of machine learning to identify spammers from known networks. There is a common pattern on SO where spammers like to create questions like that just so their other accounts can provide spam answers. Two of those answers are clearly spam (one from a known spammer on SO), and I'm letting the Drupal mods know about them. I wouldn't be surprised if there was a connection between the asker and at least one of the answerers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So the way this works is, a bunch of different users who are *suspiciously similar* to the one who asked that question have been identified as spammers elsewhere on the network.

**That does NOT mean this user is a spammer!**

But... Spammers *do* often post fake "recommend me a product" questions so that other spammers can answer them with recommendations for the products they wish to hawk.

Take the hint from the system as an indicator that you should be *extra careful* before giving the author the benefit of the doubt: there's something fishy going on, and the author *might* be involved in it.

If you're not *sure*, don't mark it as spam.

But since it's a crap question, close it. Since you're a moderator, maybe go ahead and delete it straight away - if you want to leave a comment for the author, you're free to do this and know that he'll be notified.

The best thing in this scenario is just to get it off the site as quickly as possible - there's nothing to be gained from *encouraging* these roving bands of spammers.